# import table entries from text file

Tags: tables, longtable, input, import

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
\begin{longtable}{| c | l |}
\hline \textbf{Short name }& \textbf{Description} \\
%assume all lines in the text are '\hline <name> & description \\'
\input{logs/some_entries.txt}
\input{logs/other_entries.txt}
%[...]
\hline
\end{longtable}
```

Where the text files are bash-generated.

If I copy-paste the input of the text files, the pdf is built correctly. Trying to use the files like this, though, will result in

```
! Misplaced \noalign.\hline ->\noalign{\ifnum 0=`}\fi \penalty \@M \futurelet \@let@token \LT@@h... \hline
```

How do I make this work?

**EDIT**

Minimal "working" example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{| c | l |}
\hline \textbf{Short name }& \textbf{Location} \\
\hline Google & \url{https://google.com} \\ 
\input{some_entries.txt}
\hline
\end{longtable} 

\end{document}
```

where `some_entries.txt` contains

```
\hline TEX & \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com}\\%
```

Comment: How about if you move `some_entries.txt` to the same directory as the `tex` file and use `\input{some_entries.txt}`?  Also a full MWE always helps, i.e. does the same error happen with no packages and `\documentclass{article}`

Comment: @DaiBowen Neither seems to work.

Comment: What do your `some_entries.txt` look like?  Can you reduce this to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) we can copy and paste and compile locally to replicate the error.

Comment: @DaiBowen done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
...
\makeatletter %must be!
\newcommand ...
\makeatother % must be!
\begin{document}
...
\begin{longtable}{| c | l |} \hline
\textbf{Short name }& \textbf{Description} \\
%assume all lines in the text are '\hline <name> & description \\'
\ExpandableInput{test01.txt}
\ExpandableInput{test02.txt}
...
\hline
\end{longtable}
```

test01.txt:

```
\hline name & description \\
\hline myname & mydescription \\
```

test02.txt:

```
\hline name2 & description2 \\
\hline name3 & description3 \\
```

Comment: Indeed it does. Forgot to add the ``\makeatletter`` and ``makeatother`` (what do they do?). Thank you.

Comment: @Stefan: Thank you for makeing the code readable - this online-editor doesn't like me.

Comment: @User1291: Because of the ambersand - maybee this is theory?

Answer (score 1):

The errormessage indicates that one \hline is not at the beginning of a table row. Try to put a % at the end of each of our included files (or at each line of them?).

Comment: nope, doesn't work.

Comment: Try http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=3970

Comment: ``! Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>$ \ExpandableInput{logs/some_entries.txt}``

Comment: same if I just use ``\@@input{logs/some_entries.txt}`` directly